# Convert .jpg to .eps format

Tags: linux, jpeg, eps

How can I convert multiple .jpg files to .eps files on Linux?

Answer (score 31):

When using the ImageMagick's convert, it is a good practice to use the eps2 format. This make the resulting eps file much smaller because it uses the JPEG compression algorithm (DCT).

So, to convert `a.jpg` to `a.eps` do:

```
convert a.jpg eps2:a.eps
```

This of course, can be used in a shell script, to convert multiple JPG to EPS.

Comment: I get the following errors when I execute :
`convert: unable to open image `pic.jpg': ��. @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2489.`
`convert: unable to open image `pic.jpg':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2489.`
`convert: missing an image filename `eps2:pic.eps' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2940.`
What should I do?

Comment: Use imagemagick `mogrify` command instead of convert for multiple files.

`mogrify -format eps3 *.png`

Answer (score 9):

You can use many tools. I recommend using `convert` command from ImageMagick.

```
#!/bin/bash

# example 1
convert myfile.jpg myfile.eps

# example 2
for file in file1.jpg file2.jpg file3.jpg; do
    echo convert "$file" $(echo "$file" | sed 's/\.jpg$/\.eps/')
done
```

To make example 2 run you need to remove the `echo` inside the `for`-loop. Make sure the commands it outputs are correct **before** removing it.

Answer (score 6):

According to user1958943, I used the convert tool as well. However, as the eps3 format gives an even better compression with similar quality as eps2, I suggest to use

```
convert a.jpg eps3:a.eps
```

By the way, this tool also works for png files (and also others) ...

Does anybody know which compression eps3 is using?

Comment: what is the difference between eps2 and eps3?

Comment: Version 3 is specified in appendix H of the following document: https://www-cdf.fnal.gov/offline/PostScript/PLRM2.pdf. The changes to version 2 are listed in section H.8. However, I am not sure whether you find the details about compression there...

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to combine [jpegtopnm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/jpegtopnm.html) and [pnmtops](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pnmtops.html) from the [netpbm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/) toolkit.
This will however produce PS, not EPS.

```
for f in *.jpg
do
  g=`echo "$f" | sed 's/\.jpg$/\.eps/'`
  echo "$f -> $g" 1>&2
  jpegtopnm $f | pnmtops > $g
done
```

Comment: This produces a PNG file, not an EPS. You probably want to use `pnmtops` instead of `pnmtopng`.

Comment: @the paul: Yikes; thanks; fixed.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick's [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) can do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I do this often and sometimes on Windows. Hence, I wrote a small online converter which uses convert:

[JPG to EPS Converter](http://www.fclose.com/t/jpg2eps/).

Hope this can also help others.